# sqlalchemy-flask: How to count self relation

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following model:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = "commenting_comment"

    id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True, index=True)
    text = Column(String)
    
    parent_id = Column(UUID, ForeignKey('commenting_comment.id'))
    parent = relationship('Comment', remote_side=[id], backref="replies")
```

I want to count the number of `replies` for each Comment.
Currently, I have the following query:

```
ids = ["uuid1", "uuid2", "uuid3"]
qs = db.query(
    Comment,
    func.count('id').label("replies_count"),
).select_from(Comment).group_by(Comment.id).filter(
    Comment.id.in_(ids)
).all()
```

There are two problems: 
1- It returns `replies_count=1` for all of the rows.
2- I want `replies_count` to be in the comment's body but it returns `replies_count` out of the comment body. (as follows)

```
comments = [
    {"Comment": {...}, "replies_count": 1},
    {"Comment": {...}, "replies_count": 1},
]
```

How can I solve these two problems?

**UPDATE**
In Django corresponding query will be:

```
Comment.objects.filter(id__in=ids).annotate(replies_count=Count("replies"))
```

But I don't know how to implement it in the flask and sqlalchemy.